# Trying to return specific line in txt file using PHP

Tags: php, html

```
    <?php
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];

$file = file_get_contents('directory.txt');
$searchfname = stripos($file, $fname);
$searchlname = stripos($file, $lname);

$lines = file('directory.txt');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
foreach($lines as $line){
    if (($searchfname !== false) && ($searchlname !== false)){
        echo $line;
    }
}
?>
```

My current code. The problem I am facing is that it echos the entirety of the txt file. How do I make it only print the line where it matches the $fname and $lname?

```
John Doe daahl92@gmail.com 57123466930 1192 Broad Pl Herndon AR 20170.
dave attard hockyren97@aim.com 235626930 dfgdfg Reston AK 20171.
jason Green daahl97@gmail.com 571245930 1192 Way Pl Reston TN 20176.
```

This is my text file.

```
    <?php
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip= $_POST['zip'];

$fh = fopen("directory.txt", "a+");
fwrite($fh, "$fname $lname $email $phone $address $city $state $zip\n");
fclose($fh);
?>
```

This is the php file to populate my text file with contacts. When I try to echo a specific line it echos all the lines.

Comment: ...and this is why databases were invented. Save yourself the pain. Even if you don't want to setup mysql or something, a little SQLite database would make this much easier.

Comment: It's for a PHP class :/

Comment: That's a terrible file format, how do you figure out where the address ends and the city starts? You could at least use tab separation.

Comment: At worst, use JSON format to store the data then you don't have to decode it yourself (And as mentioned above, your file format is ambiguous anyway as to which part is which). Then you can decode it to an array in PHP and use PHP's array-searching abilities to find matching data.

Comment: Don't you need to use stripos on `$line` as part of your loop, not on the entire file just as you've read it in? I'm not sure what those two lines are achieving, other than to check that the names do exist somewhere in the file, though not necessarily on the same line.

Comment: But yeah as droopsnoot says your issue is that your stripos searches the entire file, so it'll always find the value if it exists _somewhere_  in the file. You need to test each line individually.

Comment: doesnt the foreach loop i have accomplish this?

Comment: No, because it compares the searched-for value to the result of searching the whole file. You need to stripos each individual line. e.g. `$searchfname` is not updated for each new line, is it? You have set that once, from searching the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to simply loop through the array and check to see if stripos returns a NON false result. I combined the first and last names to a single string since you are expecting them together. I added an exit so that the loop is exited if your result is found.

```
<?php
    $fname = "jason";
    $lname = "Green";
    $needle = "$fname $lname";

    $lines = file('directory.txt');
    
    foreach($lines as $line){
        if(stripos($line,$needle) !== false){
            echo "Line: $line";
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank you so much this works perfectly and i understand what my issues were now!